# Rails Show View Showing Wrong Record's Information

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a fairly simple model called `Inquiry` and am using the show page to show the record of an instance, yet no matter which instance I try to show, it displays the information for the same record.

Here's my controller for `show` and `index`:

```
  def index
    @inquiries = Inquiry.all
    @inquiry = Inquiry.find_by(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @inquiry = Inquiry.find_by(params[:id])
  end
```

And here's my `inquiry#show` view:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center"><%= @inquiry.project_name %></h1>

  <div class="row">
    <hr class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-3">
  </div> <!-- row -->

  <h2><strong>Client: </strong><%= @inquiry.name %></h2>
  <h3><strong>Email: </strong><%= @inquiry.email %></h3>
  <h3><strong>Project Components: </strong></h3>
    <ul>
      <% if @inquiry.site_design %><li>Site Design</li><% end %>
      <% if @inquiry.development %><li>Development</li><% end %>
      <% if @inquiry.copywriting %><li>Copywriting/Content</li><% end %>
      <% if @inquiry.social_media %><li>Social Media</li><% end %>
      <% if @inquiry.seo %><li>SEO</li><% end %>
      <% if @inquiry.branding %><li>Branding</li><% end %>
      <% if @inquiry.print_materials %><li>Print Materials</li><% end %>
      <% if @inquiry.graphic_design %><li>Graphic Design</li><% end %>
      <% if @inquiry.logo_design %><li>Logo Design</li><% end %>
    </ul>
  <h3><strong>Project Details: </strong></h3>
  <p><%= @inquiry.other %></p>

  <div class="row">
    <hr class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-3">
  </div> <!-- row -->

  <h3 class="text-center"><%= link_to "Back to Index", inquiries_path %></h3>
</div> <!-- container -->
```

And here's how I'm accessing it, but the url confirms that I am in fact viewing different records, so I don't think this could be the problem:

```
<% @inquiries.each do |m| %>
    ...
    <td><%= link_to "Details", inquiry_path(m) %></td>
    ...
<% end %>
```

No matter which record I click on, it seems always to show me the first record in my database.  Can anyone see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you are calling `find_by` which is incorrect.   You would want to find by id.  The line would look like this:

```
 def show
   @inquiry = Inquiry.find(params[:id])
 end
```

If you don't want the exception, you can find_by_id instead.

Comment: Excellent!  I knew it was something stupid I was overlooking.  Should I change that for the index method as well?

Comment: You shouldn't get a param[:id] for your index method so you should remove the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find_by_id` or simply `.find`.

```
@inquiry = Inquiry.find_by_id(params[:id])
#or
@inquiry = Inquiry.find(params[:id])
```